Recovering eth in a blank address
I know this may be awkward but I am doing it as a last resort so I can have a closure and move on to other things.
Here's the situation.
I deployed a smart contract on chain A (arbitrum).
I mistakenly sent eth to the same contract address on chain B (mainnet).
I deployed smart contract on chain A at 0 nonce.
I have used up to the 5th nonce on chain A's deployer on chain B(mainnet). That is to say i have used the 0 nonce on the eoa on the mainnet.
Are there any attainable options to retrieve the eth on the blank address on chain B(mainnet)?
Also note worthy is that the deployment on chain A(arbitrum) was a normal create and not create2.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Unfortunately once a nonce has been used it is no longer possible to reuse it.
